# 組込み機器内 DebianでのPython3パッケージの確認方法

Tags: python, debian

Debian10をベースとしたOSを搭載した組込み機器内で実行されるPythonアプリがあり、
それをVMware上でエミュレートする環境を構築中です。
VMware上でPythonアプリを実行すると、とあるパッケージの関数がないというエラーで、おそらくパッケージバージョンなどの違いがあると推測しています。

組込み機器内では、正常にPythonスクリプトが動いています。
組込み機器内でのPythonパッケージが確認できません。

## 確認したこと

pip3 list:pip3が存在していません。
python3 -m pip list：pipがありません。
python3 -m pip3 list：pipがありません。

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packagesにパッケージが存在しているようです。
しかし、確信がありません。上記で問題としたパッケージ自体が存在していないためです。

なぜpipがなくパッケージが存在しているのでしょうか？
適用されるパッケージの一覧を調べるためにはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: これらの記事が参考になるかも。[【Python】モジュール（ライブラリ）の一覧を取得](https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/module-list-py/), [Pythonのモジュール、関数、クラスを文字列から取得する](https://blog.imind.jp/entry/2020/05/05/112729), [pythonで現在の環境にインストールされているパッケージの一覧取得](https://qiita.com/podhmo/items/44f202e2502cb0f03020), [AWS Lambdaで利用できるPythonライブラリの一覧をpkg_resourcesを使って確認してみた](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/aws-lambda-python-library-list-with-pkg-resources/)

Comment: oririさん回答の冒頭にあるようなことは、この記事 [Finding pip on Your System](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/#finding-pip-on-your-system) の項の **note** に書かれていますね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「Debian10をベースとしたOS」での Pythonパッケージの確認方法, について

まず, OS(システム)側で Pythonを利用する環境 (*NIX環境ではよくある) では
OS側のパッケージ管理システムで管理されていることがあり, pip利用は控えたほうがよいでしょう
システム側で利用しているパッケージを上書きするとシステムが不安定になるので

Pythonパッケージのバージョンは, APT系パッケージ管理システムなら以下のように
(`--installed` 指定なら インストール済み だけ, オプションなしならすべて)

```bash
$ apt list python* --installed
一覧表示... 完了
python-apt-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 2.4.0ubuntu1 all [インストール済み、自動]
python-is-python3/jammy,jammy,now 3.9.2-2 all [インストール済み]
python3-apport/jammy-updates,jammy-updates,now 2.20.11-0ubuntu82.3 all [インストール済み、自動]
python3-apt/jammy-updates,now 2.4.0ubuntu1 amd64 [インストール済み、自動]
python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets/jammy,jammy,now 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu39 all [インストール済み、自動]
python3-aptdaemon/jammy,jammy,now 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu39 all [インストール済み、自動]
python3-blinker/jammy,jammy,now 1.4+dfsg1-0.4 all [インストール済み、自動]
python3-brlapi/jammy-updates,now 6.4-4ubuntu3 amd64 [インストール済み、自動]
python3-cairo/jammy,now 1.20.1-3build1 amd64 [インストール済み、自動]
python3-certifi/jammy,jammy,now 2020.6.20-1 all [インストール済み、自動]
(略)
```

また, 以下のような確認も可能 (パッケージによっては `__version__` ではないかもしれない)

```py
$ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.__
psutil.__all__             psutil.__eq__(             psutil.__le__(             psutil.__reduce_ex__(
psutil.__annotations__     psutil.__file__            psutil.__loader__          psutil.__repr__()
psutil.__author__          psutil.__format__(         psutil.__lt__(             psutil.__setattr__(
psutil.__cached__          psutil.__ge__(             psutil.__name__            psutil.__sizeof__()
psutil.__class__(          psutil.__getattribute__(   psutil.__ne__(             psutil.__spec__
psutil.__delattr__(        psutil.__gt__(             psutil.__new__(            psutil.__str__()
psutil.__dict__            psutil.__hash__()          psutil.__package__         psutil.__subclasshook__(
psutil.__dir__(            psutil.__init__(           psutil.__path__            psutil.__version__
psutil.__doc__             psutil.__init_subclass__(  psutil.__reduce__()
>>> psutil.__version__
'5.9.0'
```

---

**仮想環境**

Debianなど, システム側で Pythonが利用されている場合, Pythonパッケージ使用する時は virtual environment (仮想環境)使います (VMWare などとは異なる)
venv, pipenv, poetry, Anaconda などがある

参考: (docs.python.org) [venv --- 仮想環境の作成](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/venv.html)

- Anacondaや pipenvの 仮想環境などでは, その環境に activate しないと, (その環境の)パッケージは扱えない
- activateすれば, それら仮想環境の パッケージ管理コマンドでバージョンのリストを得ることができるはず (大抵それは pipではないコマンド)