# Debian環境のPython3でpipを使用せずにパッケージをインストールする方法

Tags: python, debian

## 質問内容

組込みDebian10環境下で、後述するようなパッケージインストール状態でした。
同じように再現するために、どのようにPythonパッケージを確認・インストールするのでしょうか？

## aptパッケージの確認

以下のようにPythonに関するパッケージは以下のようでした。
pipが存在していません。しかし、Pythonインタプリタでは、パッケージインストール先にあるパッケージがimportできます。

```
apt list python* --installed

python3-minimal/now 3.7.3-1 armhf [installed,local]
python3-six/now 1.12.0-1 all [installed,local]
python3.7-minimal/now 3.7.3-2+deb10u2 armhf [installed,local]
python3.7/now 3.7.3-2+deb10u2 armhf [installed,local]
python3/now 3.7.3-1 armhf [installed,local]
```

## パッケージのインストール先

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/
```

## 参考資料

前の質問
[組込み機器内 DebianでのPython3パッケージの確認方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/94399/%e7%b5%84%e8%be%bc%e3%81%bf%e6%a9%9f%e5%99%a8%e5%86%85-debian%e3%81%a7%e3%81%aepython3%e3%83%91%e3%83%83%e3%82%b1%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b8%e3%81%ae%e7%a2%ba%e8%aa%8d%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95)
参考URL
[The reason cause different location of python packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234344/the-reason-cause-different-location-of-python-packages)

## 試したこと

他サイトに紹介されていたようなaptパッケージでのインストールを試みました。

```
sudo apt install python3-(パッケージ名)
sudo apt install python3.7-(パッケージ名)
```

Pillow、django、flower、redis等がインストールされているのですが、上記の方法ではインストールできません。

## 追記

情報が不足していたので、追記します。

### 状況

Debian10の組込み機器を開発するためにVMwareでOSイメージが提供されています。
それを使用して、開発・ブートイメージ作成→実機適用という流れです。
他の人が作成した組込み機器は既に動作済みのアプリ等が動いております。
ただし、それを作製した開発環境がなく、実機から動いているものから再現を試みています。手元のVMwareのOSイメージはデフォルト状態になっています。
実機にログインして、手元のVMware上との違いを探りつつ再現している状態です。

### 実機内での調査

上記のaptパッケージ確認とは、実機にTeraTermログインしてコマンドラインで得た結果です。
また、パッケージの確認方法は、あたりをつけて、インストールフォルダをWinSCPで確認しました。さらに、実機内でPythonを起動して、各パッケージが実際にimportできることを確認しております。
この実機内でaptでもなく、pipもない状況でなぜPythonパッケージがインストールされているのかが分からないです。

Comment: まず `apt search キーワード` で検索してみましょう。python3-pip パッケージは armhf 向けにも存在するようです。 https://packages.debian.org/search?arch=armhf&keywords=python3-pip

Comment: `--installed` はインストール済みパッケージを意味し, これからインストールするものを探すのに適していない。あと, システムに影響しないように普通は仮想環境用意することになるはず。またその場合さらにどのような仮想環境選択するかも

Comment: 組み込み実機にインストールしているパッケージを調べているので、--installedでも良いのかと思いました。再現したいのは、VMware上の仮想環境下で組込み機器内環境と同じようにしたいのです。

Comment: apt searchでもPythonパッケージは出てきません。

Comment: 実機ではpython3-pipが存在しない状態で、どうやってパッケージをインストールしたのかが分からずに困っています。最悪、仮想環境ではpipで入れても動作するような気はしますけど。

Comment: 「どうやってインストールしたのかわからないパッケージ」が存在しているというのが質問のポイントのようですが、その話が書かれていません。それが何で、どうやって確認したのかが要りそうです。（パッケージのインストール先 /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ というところで「書いたつもり」なのかもしれませんが伝わってません）

Comment: 実機は, 多分仮想環境を利用しているのでしょう ([回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/94399/組込み機器内-debianでのpython3パッケージの確認方法/94401#94401) に付けたように)。(多分としか言いよう無いけれど)

Comment: 実は単に pip を使ってインストールした後に pip(や関連のディレクトリ等) を uninstall あるいは削除したとか？ こちらの記事 [Where Are Python Packages Installed in Linux](https://linuxhint.com/python-packages-installed-linux/) の **Where Are Python Packages When Installed Through Pip** に書かれている、pip コマンドでインストールしたパッケージの例とディレクトリの階層等が同様になっているようです。組み込み環境ということを考えると変更される可能性を排除したかったとか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ソースコードを持ってくれば、中に`setup.py`というスクリプトがあるはずなので、それを実行してインストールできます。

```
python3 setup.py install
```

ただし、

- インストールされるのはそのパッケージのみで、依存しているパッケージはインストールされません。一つ一つインストールする必要があります。
- 拡張モジュール(C言語などで書かれたもの)を含むパッケージは、C言語の開発環境が必要です。(pipでのインストールでも場合によっては同じですが、この場合 **必ず** です)

めんどくさいですよね。
だからみんな、「pipでインストールしろ」というわけで。

あと、この方法でインストールしたものは、パッケージ管理されません。
アンインストールする場合には、手動でインストールしたファイルを削除しなければなりません。

[setup.pyを用いてインストールしたモジュールのアンインストール方法](https://qiita.com/orion0616/items/dfe476067e499cca8535)

もしくは、debianであればdebパッケージを作成して管理します。
以下は、自分が昔debパッケージを作る際に参考にしたサイトです。
ただし、かなり古いので、今はまた違っているかもしれません。

- [python3用とpython2用のmultipleなdebパッケージを作るubuntuパッケージの作り方](https://bellbind.hatenadiary.org/entry/20100728/1280334070)
- [pythonパッケージからdebファイルを作成する](https://qiita.com/ukinau/items/adeadf2333b5cce54614)

一般的にaptで管理しているpythonパッケージ(pythonに限った話ではないですが)は、誰かのところでdebパッケージを作成して、それを配布していると思います。
だから、pipなどがインストールされていなくてもモジュールがインストールできます。

Comment: なるほど、おそらくこの状態であると推測できますね。